# Restrict access to Symfony 3.4 route/method to one specific role using annotations

Tags: php, symfony, hierarchy, roles, symfony-3.4

I have a role hierarchy in `security.yml` that looks like this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPERVISOR:   ROLE_USER
    ROLE_MANAGER:      ROLE_SUPERVISOR
    ROLE_SUPPORT:      ROLE_MANAGER
    ROLE_ADMIN:        ROLE_SUPPORT
```

In my controller I have the following definitions:

```
/**
 * Collect user details.
 *
 * @Route(
 *      "/course/site/new/customerdetails",
 *      name = "course_site_new_customerdetails"
 * )
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function customerDetailsAction(Request $request): Response
{
    // prevent a manager from entering
    if ($this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('supervisor_index');
    }
```

**Using annotations**, is there a way that I can prevent access to this method/route for Managers, but let Supervisors in?

I know the obvious change would be to redefine the hierarchy, however Supervisors are "below" Managers in the chain.

Comment: `@IsGranted('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')` should do it. this will also deny managers and all other users that aren't supervisors

Comment: @Jakumi No, seemingly not. That was my first attempt but I believe because `MANAGER` inherits from `SUPERVISOR` then it gets through (when I don't want that to be the case)

Comment: I see ... try https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html#security and maybe `@Security("is_granted('ROLE_SUPERVISOR') and not is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')")`

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks, I think that would work for me. Feel free to post this as an answer and i'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I thought about it again, think the answer is better ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@IsGranted` is limited to ROLES and privileges voted on by security voters (roles are voted on by a specific voter) since your manager role apparently includes the supervisor role (for whatever reason). [Hierarchies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles) in the sense of roles work the way, that it essentially a tree, where the user role is at the root and it branches out from that one. The rules for your roles essentially should be:

```
ROLE_MANAGER: ROLE_USER
ROLE_SUPERVISOR: ROLE_MANAGER
```

which should be read as "every manager is a user", and "every supervisor is a manager". With that one, `@IsGranted('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')` should be sufficient.

However, you can be more explicit by using the `@Security` syntax and demand that the user returns a specific role on `User::getRoles()`:

```
@Security("'ROLE_SUPERVISOR' in user.getRoles()")
```

(maybe `user.roles` is enough ... but I'm not quite sure).

don't forget the use clause:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
```

Also please note, that roles are cached until logout.

Comment: `user.getRoles()` is indeed required and works well. Thank you.